# Is there a criminal database for my city Calgary

Tags: criminal-law

About 15 years ago while my father was working 55 hour weeks being paid $8/hr, he completed his taxi license and started working more hours a week as a taxi driver. On the highway, one of his passengers struck him with a hammer on the back of his head landing him in the hospital for a few months for no apparent reason.

My father, being an immigrant, did not understand the law or his rights so did not pursue the issue further, despite police catching the individual in question.

I, his son, would like to look at this case and pursue it, despite my father's unwillingness to do so. Is there a way that I, independently, can figure out the identity of the criminal. The city in question is Calgary, Alberta, Canada.

Comment: This sounds like you're on the hunt for vengeance. You're asking, by the title, if there's a list of criminals you can look over and I assume that's because it seems like the best place to start if you're looking for such a person **yourself**. Of course the police would be looking this stuff over themselves if you were in cooperation with them. I'd caution against this, you're way too close to the issue and you're probably not a licensed private investigator. This sounds like a recipe to bring more problems to your life, not solutions.

Comment: In addition, chances are if the police caught that individual, they probably charged with an offence, and he was probably convicted. While I'm sorry to hear what happened to your father, you're not going to gain anything by trying to investigate the matter yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pursue it.

Criminal charges are a matter for provincial prosecutors; if they have decided not to then that is the end of the matter.

A civil claim would be barred by the statute of limitations. In any event, you have no standing is you have not suffered  injury as a result of this man's actions.

Comment: +1 and I'm kind of put off by the whole tone of the OP. He's asking if there's a list of criminals for his city, and making it sound like he's looking to track down this person himself, without his fathers help. Sounds like a vengeance plan more than a question like "How can I help the police find this guy 15 years later."

Comment: Also of note - court records are legally allowed to be destroyed/removed after 14 years of the case - so even then, notes of the case wouldn't be found.